# how to fix the Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_0900_as_cs,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,IMPLICIT)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Here is my query:

```
   PROCEDURE `fetch_g_qjo_attribute_link_pagination`(IN language varchar (255),
    $pageNo int(10),
    $pageSize int(10)
    )
    BEGIN
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    declare lang_id int;
    declare rec_offset int;
    if $pageNo is null 
    then 
        set $pageNo=1; 
    end if;       
    if $PageSize is null 
    then 
        set $PageSize=10; 
    end if;
    set rec_offset = ($pageNo - 1)* $PageSize;     
    
    set lang_id = (select l.id from data_language l where l.iso_code = language);
    -- -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
     
    
    (select sl.*, gn.attribute_name, gv.attribute_value, gs.subpart_name
    from
    g_qjo_attribute_link sl,
    g_attribute_name_value_type_lin gl,
    g_attribute_name gn,
    g_attribute_value gv,
    g_subpart gs
    where gl.id = sl.attribute_id
    and gl.attribute_name_code = gn.attribute_name_code
    and gl.attribute_value_code = gv.attribute_value_code
    and gl.subpart_code <>''
    and gs.subpart_code = gl.subpart_code)
    union
    (select sl.*, gn.attribute_name, gv.attribute_value, '' as subpart_name
    from
    g_qjo_attribute_link sl,
    g_attribute_name_value_type_lin gl,
    g_attribute_name gn,
    g_attribute_value gv,
    g_subpart gs
    where gl.id = sl.attribute_id
    and gl.attribute_name_code = gn.attribute_name_code
    and gl.attribute_value_code = gv.attribute_value_code
    and gl.subpart_code ='')
    order by id ASC
    limit rec_offset,$pageSize;
    END
```

It throws this error:

> I am getting this error while executing the store procedure. Can
> anyone please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extremely strange error message...

Comment: LIMIT parameters cannot be taken from the variable, use dynamic SQL.